# I am trying to create an inter-satellite network and run an inter-satellite routing protocols

Tags: stk-agi

I am trying to create a simulation of a network of cube sats connected to Earth station to provide me with internet. I want to run on these satellite a routing protocols can this be done using [STK software](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_Tool_Kit) and can somebody tell me how to do it or provide me with a Youtube video or pdf tutorial?

Comment: You need help creating software for cubesat or simulation?

Comment: no i want to simulate a cubesats network to provide me with internet via connecting to some ground station and i want to run on these sats a bunch of dyanmic routing protocols for the inter-satellite links for expamle a DTN protocol and see what is its impact on the network and also run BP protocol and see what will be more suitable for my topolgy is this even posible using STK-agi sowftware ? and thanks for your interst